# Read in number file and calculate average in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a txtfile called "averages" that looks like:

```
1 4 5 3 -1
2 8 9 3 2 -1
4 8 15 16 23 42 -1
3 -1
```

I want to be able to read in each line and calculate the average of each line whenever a "-1" is reached. I have written the code to read in the file and print it to the command line, I'm just having trouble finding the averages of each line. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            String currentLine;

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("averages.txt"));
            while  ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(currentLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)reader.close();
            } catch (IOException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by doing the following:

- split the `currentLine` using split method:

  ```
  String[] nums = currnetLine.split("\\s+");
  ```
- loop over the `nums` and parse each elements to `int` then add it to a
  `sum` variable

  ```
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      int num = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
      if(num != -1) {
          sum += num;
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally calculate the average.

  ```
  sum/(nums.length - 1);// -1 because you need to execlude the -1 at the end of your line
  ```

Comment: So in this case the average would be sum/nums.length?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The -1 part was what I wasn't getting. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
int sum = 0;

String[] values = currentLine.split(" ");

for (String value : values) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(value);

    if (n < 0) {
        break;
    }

    sum += n;
}

int count = values.length - 1;
// calculate average from sum and count
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7+, the Scanner object is available and has a variety of useful functions to use.

1.) First read in the line
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1 51 2 52");

2.) From your code above, if you have a space delimiter, it is easy to work with
scanner.useDelimiter(" ");

3.) If scanner.hasNext() then scanner.next()  for the next string.

Iterate the list using Integer.parseInt("1") to get the value, sum, then average.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            String currentLine;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("averages.txt"));
            while  ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(currentLine);
                StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(currentLine," ");
                int count=st.countTokens();
                int array[]=new int[count-1];
                int i=0;
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()&&i!=count-1)
             {
                array[i]=Integer.valueOf(st.nextToken());
                i=i+1;
             }
        int sum=0;
            for(int x=0;x<array.length;x++)
                {
                    sum=sum+array[x];
                }
        float average=(float)sum/array.length;
        System.out.println("The average of this line is: "+average);
            }
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)reader.close();
            } catch (IOException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
}
```

My logic is that you read a line at a time and separate them by spaces. Then you convert those separated string into Integer. Last step is add them up and do some math to get the average.

Hope this helps. Thanks!